# Hover colour of hyperlink in HTML

Tags: html, hyperlink, href

I'd like to make it so that when the mouse hovers over my hyperlink it changes colour. As it stands it remains black and so it is hard to see that the text is a hyperlink.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<h4 style="text-align: left;"><a href="hyperlink" target="_blank"><span style="color: #000000;">The making of #bobthebrewbus</span></a></h4>
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
    a:hover {color: red;}
    a { color: black; text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<h4 style="text-align: left;"><a href="hyperlink" target="_blank">The making of #bobthebrewbus</a></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following CSS:

```
h4 a:hover span {
    color: red !important; // Change the color to your preference.
}
```

the `:hover` guides what happens when anchor is hovered upon. I added `!important` just so that it can overwrite the inline css in `span` element. You might not need the `!important` declaration, if you move the inline CSS to external CSS.

Comment: I'm working on a wordpress site and flipping to text to edit so it is only in HTML. Can I change to CSS or how to I translate this into HTML and add to the code?

Comment: You need to write CSS in style tags, in the document. Pseudo classes (like :hover) never refer to an element, but to any element that satisfies the conditions of the stylesheet rule.

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style type="text/css">
<!--
a:link {color: #000000; text-decoration: underline; }
a:active {color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline; }
a:visited {color: #008000; text-decoration: underline; }
a:hover {color: #ff0000; text-decoration: none; }
-->
</style>
```